# No effect when changing BEAMER_THEME

Tags: org-mode, beamer

I don't get any effect if I put the following line at the start of my Org-mode file:

```
#+BEAMER_THEME: metropolis
```

Indeed, whatever theme name I write after `#+BEAMER_THEME:`, there's not mention of it in the resulting `.tex` file, and I always get the default theme.

I'm using Org mode 9.5 and Emacs 27.2. Am I missing something here? What's the correct way to change the Beamer theme?

EDIT: I'm using Doom Emacs v2.0.9

Comment: One common error that might be causing this is that you are doing `C-c C-e l l` (LaTeX export) instead of `C-c C-e l b` (Beamer export). Does the `\documentclass` line say `beamer`?

Comment: @NickD Seems I can't paste a screenshot in the comments, but in my export buffer in Org-mode I don't have any export key specific to Beamer. In the `[l] Export to LaTeX` section, I only have `[L] As LaTeX buffer`, `[p] As PDF file`, `[l] As LaTeX file`, and `[o] As PDF file and open` options. Is there any package I should install or is the Beamer export supposed to be available by default?

Yes, the first line of the generated LaTeX file is the following: `\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}`

Comment: `(require 'ox-beamer)` - add this to your init file towards the end.

Comment: I found `M-x org-beamer-export-to-pdf` works, and once I ran it, it added the specific Beamer export option in my Org-mode export buffer!

Comment: That's because it's an autoloaded function: when it is invoked for the first time, the file where it is defined is loaded (which is what the `require` form does) and then the function is executed. Do `C-h i g (emacs) Lisp libraries` to learn more about autoloads, loading libraries, the `load-path` and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`beamer` export is *different* from `latex` export: for `latex`, you say `C-c C-e l l` (or similar - this produces a TeX file but does not process it to PDF); for `beamer`, you say `C-c C-e l b` (again this produces a TeX file but does not process it - there are other options specific to `beamer` export for processing to PDF).

If you don't have these entries in the menu, then `beamer` export is not enabled. To enable it, go to the `*scratch*` buffer and type `(require 'ox-beamer)` followed by `C-j`: that enables it for this session. To enable it permanently, add `(require 'ox-beamer)` to your init file (I'd add it towards the end, after the rest of Org mode initialization, but that's probably not necessary).